# Custom class with pop() method not returning correct new length of list

Tags: python, class, iterator, stack, binary-search-tree

I have a custom class in Python that's supposed to behave like a Stack. For some reason when I'm trying to traverse a tree and add nodes to it, everytime i pop from the list it doesn't seem to change its size.

The code is breaking infinitely looping at the print statements, but I'm not sure why. Pop() should be reducing the number of items, but len(self.items) either returns 3 or 4 every loop.

**Class definitions:**

```
import collections



class Stack:
    def __init__(self, items=[]):
        self.items = items
        self.idx = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        self.idx += 1
        try:
            return self.items[0-self.idx]
        except IndexError:
            self.idx = 0
            raise StopIteration


    # isEmpty() - returns True if stack is empty and false otherwise
    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.items:
            return False
        return True
    # push() - Insert item at the top of the stack
    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)
        return

    # pop() - Remove and return element from top of the stack,
    # provided it is not empty
    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    # also known as peek() - return top element from stack without removing,
    #
    def top(self):
        return self.items[-1]

class Node():
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Tree:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.root = None
        self.items = []
        self.size = 0

        if array is not None:
            # check if input array is an actual sequence or scalar
            '''
            Items here are unchanged, only converts to Node in insert() function
            '''
            if isinstance(array,collections.abc.Sequence):
                for item in array:
                    self.insert(item)
                    self.size = self.size +1
            # if input is a single item
            else:
                self.insert(item)
                self.size = self.size +1

    # insert() - add element to corresponding location, then shuffle
    #
    def root(self):
        return self.root

    # returns parent of node v,
    # error occurs if v is root
    def parent(v):
        if v == self.items[0]:
            raise ValueError("ADT Tree - Parent can't be root (use root() instead)", e)
        return

    # returns an iterator to enumerate the children of node v
    def children(self,v):
        return
    # test wheter node v is internal
    def isInternal(self,v):
        if v.left is not None or v.right is not None:
            return True
        return False
    #test whether node v is external (i.e. leaf)
    def isExternal(self,v):
        return not self.isInternal(v)
    # test wheter node v is root
    def isRoot(v):
        return v == self.items[0]


# inherit Tree parent class
# ADT.BinaryTree(array)
# insert(), inOrder(node), preOrder(node), postOrder(node)
class BinaryTree(Tree):
    # inherit Tree parent class
    def __init__(self, array=tuple()):
        # inherit Tree methods EXCEPT init populating items
        super().__init__(None)

        # list for outputting pre/post/in order  traversals
        self.list = list()
        self.count = 0
        for item in array:
            self.insert(item)


    # test wheter node v is internal
    def isInternal(self,v):
        if v.left or v.right:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        return
    #test whether node v is external (i.e. leaf)
    def isExternal(self,v):
        if v.left or v.right:
            return False
        else:
            return True
        return




    # public
    def insert(self,value):
        self.root = self.insertRecur(self.root, value)
        self.count += 1

    # private recursive
    def insertRecur(self,current, value):
        # base case
        if (current is None):
            return Node(value)
        # traverse left
        if (value < current.value):
            current.left = self.insertRecur(current.left,value)

        # traverse right
        elif (value > current.value):
            current.right = self.insertRecur(current.right,value)

        # if current has same value as node, ignore value as a duplicate
        return current


    # accepts a node, returns a list of elements in subtree rooted at node In-order
    # L node R
    def inOrder(self,node):
        self.list = list()
        self._inOrder(node)
        return self.list

    # accepts a node, returns a list of elements in subtree rooted at node Pre-order
    # node L R
    def preOrder(self,node):
        self.list = list()
        self._preOrder(node)
        return self.list
    # accepts a node, returns a list of elements in subtree rooted at node Post-order
    # L R node
    def postOrder(self,node):
        self.list = list()
        self._postOrder(node)
        return self.list


    # L root R
    # prints current node after traversing left children AND before traversing right
    def _inOrder(self,node):
        if node is not None:
            self._inOrder(node.left)
            self.list.append(node)
            #print("{}".format(node.value),end=" ")
            self._inOrder(node.right)
        return

    # root L R
    def _preOrder(self,node):
        if node is not None:
            self.list.append(node)
            #print("{}".format(node.value),end=" ")
            self._preOrder(node.left)
            self._preOrder(node.right)
        return

    # R root L
    def _postOrder(self,node):
        if node is not None:
            self._postOrder(node.right)
            self.list.append(node)
            #print("{}".format(node.value),end=" ")
            self._postOrder(node.left)
        return
```

**Main code**
(issue is around the print statements)

```
def main():
    test = (4,5,8,9,2,1,10,3,6,7)
    newtree = BinaryTree(test)

    stk_c = Stack()
    stk_f = Stack()
    node = newtree.root
    prev = None



    while node or not stk_c.isEmpty():
        # if node has already been travelled,
        # traverse its left child
        if node is not None:
            stk_c.push(node)
            node = node.left

        elif node is None:
            node = stk_c.top()
            if node.right is None or node.right == prev:
                print("before popping stk_c" ,len(stk_c.items))
                stk_f.push(node.value)
                stk_c.pop()
                print("after popping stk_c", len(stk_c.items))
                prev=node
                node = None
            else:
                node = node.right


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: But aren't those two seperate Class instances? I thought their values wouldn't affect each other.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that.  I removed my comment.

Comment: stack_f and stack_c both share the same default list, so when yuou push to it then pop from it the lenght of that list will be the same, as you added an item then remove one. Try passing in an empty list to the stack class so they both get their own list. Alternativly change how you use the default of a list in the class

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Wow, I had no idea default args created a shared default object...thanks that solved it. Wished they pointed that out in the documentation!

Comment: You mean like here? https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-are-default-values-shared-between-objects

Comment: @Woodford You pulled that out so quick, thanks lol

Comment: As an aside, it's rather silly to reimplement `Stack`. I assume this is for a class, but in a normal app I'd just use `collections.deque` or the builtin `list`.